Arabic text issue in SSRS Report in Visual Studio 2022
I have created a report in SSRS with the extension .rdl using Visual Studio 2022. The report includes Arabic content, but when I export it to PDF, the Arabic text does not render correctly. There is no custom code involved; the report simply fetches data from a dataset.
I have attached images showing the exported output (Image-1 and Image-2) and the expected result (Image-3 and Image-4). I have already set the text direction to RTL for the Arabic content.
1.

2.

3.

4.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Found the solution using arabic font it works.Please mark this thread close

If you explain the solution in an answer to your own question, it will benefit other users.

Close this thread please

Please use the Tahoma font, which is available by default in the Windows font list. When rendered in a PDF, it will display perfectly.
